# Capistrano deploy composer error

Tags: capistrano, composer-php, capistrano3

I have an composer error while running capistrano deploy with exit code:

```
composer exit status: 2
```

Here is the full log of the error:

```
Invoke deploy:updated (first_time)
Invoke composer:install (first_time)
Execute composer:install
Invoke composer:run (first_time)
Execute composer:run
INFO[28cd8f39] Running /usr/bin/env composer install --no-dev --no-interaction --verbose --optimize-autoloader on mydomain.com
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mydomain.com: composer exit status: 2
composer stdout: Nothing written
composer stderr: Nothing written
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `block (5 levels) in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `block (3 levels) in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:172:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:186:in `with_ssh'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-composer-0.0.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-composer-0.0.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: composer exit status: 2
composer stdout: Nothing written
composer stderr: Nothing written
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status='
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:148:in `block (5 levels) in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `block (3 levels) in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:172:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:186:in `with_ssh'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:131:in `block in _execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `tap'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:128:in `_execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-composer-0.0.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:77:in `within'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-composer-0.0.4/lib/capistrano/tasks/composer.rake:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sshkit-1.5.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => composer:run
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host mydomain.com: composer exit status: 2
composer stdout: Nothing written
composer stderr: Nothing written
>
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

I am using capistrano version 3.2.0 and latest version of capistrano-composer.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

(Question answered in the comments or by an edit. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Somehow the issue was in composer install command. I've resolved the issue by running composer update before composer install, and deploy went through successfully.
>
> This is the code to run composer:update before composer:install.

```
namespace :composer do
    before 'install', 'change_dir'

    desc 'Composer update'
    task :change_dir do
        on roles(:app) do
            execute "cd #{release_path}/ && composer update"
        end
    end
end
```